# Problem with installing Clang: undefined symbol: LLVMInitializeMipsAsmParser

Tags: fedora, llvm, clang

I'm new to Linux environment. Few days ago I've installed Fedora on my laptop. I want to complie some C++ source code but having trouble with Clang. First, after installing it with *yum* I see an error (whenever I call `clang` in the console):

```
clang: symbol lookup error: clang: undefinied symbol: LLVMInitializeMipsAsmParser
```

After trying different methods I gave up on installing Clang and wanted to stick to g++. OK. but today I wanted to install some IDE. Decided to go with CodeLite and... whenever I want to open CodeLite it gives me this error:

```
/lib64/libclang.so.3.8: undefined symbol: LLVMInitializeMipsAsmParser
```

Seems like CodeLite is installing Clang by default and I ending up with the same error...

To be honest I've tried to build LLVM from source but that didn't help (I guess Clang has to know somehow where to look for those symbols and I don't know how to tell it) and I don't have enough disc space to build LLVM & Clang at the same time (it takes 20+ GB...) following instructions from here: http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html#getting-started-quickly-a-summary

Answer (score 0):

Happened the same to me, after updating clang from 3.8.0 to 3.8.1.

I installed the latest llvm library and it worked :)

```
dnf install llvm
```